# Change width of a class using Javascript and save State

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a website that has a static left Sidebar that is usually 250px wide however I have come across an issue whereby when the user is on a computer with a screen resolution where their screen is less than about 1200px the sidebar takes up far too much space on the screen.

How would I go about setting it up so that there will be a button to collapse the sidebar to 100px and it will save the state whilst they are using the website? And then once it has been collapsed there is another button for the user to expand the Sidebar back to its original state?

Also, when the user either clicks on the Collapse or Expand button, I don't want the whole page to refresh as there are a lot of forms on the site and if the page refreshes the user will have to re-enter all their details (if they click on the button mid-form).

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Use CSS media queries

Comment: `$(sidebar).width(0px)` is what you're looking for

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are asking a whole lot of questions. Each question should be a separate post, showing what you have tried

Comment: If you want to save the fact that the user decided to hide the sidebar, I would use Ajax to save a php $_SESSION.

Answer (score 4):

Best thing to do would be to set up [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) so that the sidebar is automatically resized on smaller screens without any user interaction. Here is an example(obviously you'll have to replace the selectors with the ones that apply to your page):

```
@media(min-width:992px){
    .sidebar {width:150px}
}

@media(min-width:1200px){
    .sidebar {width:250px}
}
```